# "One of the request inputs not valid" error when attempting to update Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am attempting to update an entry in Azure Table Storage.  The function is:

```
public void SaveBug(DaBug bug)
        {
            bug.PartitionKey = "bugs";
            bug.Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;

            if (bug.RowKey == null || bug.RowKey == string.Empty)
            {
                bug.RowKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                _context.AddObject(c_TableName, bug);
            }
            else
            {
                _context.AttachTo(c_TableName, bug);
                _context.UpdateObject(bug);
            }

            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

If it is a new entry (the "bug.RowKey == null" path), then it works fine.  If it is an update to an existing entity, then the "AttachTo", and the "UpdateObject" calls work, but when it gets to "SaveChanges", it throws the "One of the request inputs not valid" exception.

The class that is being stored is:

```
[DataContract]
[DataServiceKey("RowKey")]
public class DaBug
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsOpen { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string SubmittedBy { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime SubmittedDate { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string RowKey { get; set; }

    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
}
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The Timestamp property is supposed to be populated on the server-side, not sure if your client code with DateTime.Now serves any purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case anyone is looking for the answer:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/0c9d476e-7970-422a-8b34-e987e41734df

---

Working through the table context, I had to change the call from:

```
_context.AttachTo(c_TableName, bug);
```

to:

```
_context.AttachTo(c_TableName, bug, "*");
```

Comment: Thank you for saving me before I had no hair left to pull out. I went ahead and copied the actual answer into your own.

Comment: When I visit the MSDN link the page returns a "Not Authorized" error. Can you provide another link or more detailed explanation of why this workaround is necessary?

Answer (score 2):

You can also get this error if you mistakenly set the RowKey to a value you've already used (not that you'd get this problem with code in the question).  I tried to push 50+ entities in one go and accidentally had the RowKey set to the same value for two of the entities.